# Mercurial - how to see the history for a specific line of code

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I have a CSS file with thousands of lines of code. I want to see when a specific line/chunk of code was changed, without going back and reviewing each revision that changed this file (that will take a looooong time!)

Is there a way, using either TortoiseHg, Eclipse with a Mercurial plugin, or command-line, to view the history of a specific piece of code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The correct answer is `hg grep` ([Mercurial grep page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#grep)).

More deep:

```
hg grep --all "PATTERN" FILENAME
```

Sample output:

```
>hg grep --all "textdomain" functions.php
functions.php:2:-:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/translation');
functions.php:2:+:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
functions.php:1:+:load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/translation');
```

(in order - filename, revision, action, string in this revision)

Comment: I don't think this is quite a correct answer, despite it being accepted. This will search for the occurrence of a certain pattern in a file, throughout history. It will not give you the history of a specific line in a file, unless there just happens to only be one line that matches that pattern throughout history. `hg annotate` gives the right information, though you still have to manually leapfrog back through history to get the full chain of events.

Answer (score 13):

You can use:

```
hg annotate <file>
```

to find out in which revision line was changed and then use same command with `-r <revision>` at the end to go backwards through revisions.

Comment: Blame show only: 1. most recent revision of change 2. can't show info for currently deleted strings

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an option to view a specific part of a file. But to see the differences of the total file over several revisions you can use `hg diff`:

```
hg diff -r firstrevisionnumber:otherrevnumber filename
```

For example, `hg diff -r 0:8 screen.css`

Or the command `hg log screen.css`.

Comment: this is good to know, but does not help for this particular situation, as i have no idea of the range of revisions to look in, and we have almost 3,000 revisions in the history so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hg histgrep --all PATTERN FILENAME` (used to be `hg grep` in the older versions, and that doesn't work anymore)