# Mercurial track changes of a line

Tags: mercurial

I am curious if there is a possibility to see the changes of a file, in an automatic way that have occurred to a line using Mercurial...

Concrete case: at some time in the past, a few months ago a line in our code (file: MainWindow.cpp line number 219) was changed by someone, and noone remembers when and what was there before, we just know that the stuff we have now is not working :( and we would like to see why (and most importantly **when**) that change is there. Browsing manually through the thousands of commits is not an option :(

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
hg annotate MainWindow.cpp
```

It's similar to `svn blame`, and displays all lines of the file with the number of revision when it changed.

Comment: He doesn't want to know the user that changed it.... he wants to know the changeset that changed it so the `-u` option shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thx Steve, must have overlooked that - to be honest, I was sure the username was asked... Anyway I've updated the text.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `hg annotate` and default output of annotate will show you revision, when sting was changed last time

```
hg ann functions.php
0: <?php
0:
0: if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 550;
0:
3: add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');
6: add_theme_support('custom-background');
...
```

(first column is revision number). With -d option you can add date of revision to output

```
hg ann -d -n functions.php
0 Sat Aug 06 01:13:35 2011 +0600: <?php
0 Sat Aug 06 01:13:35 2011 +0600:
0 Sat Aug 06 01:13:35 2011 +0600: if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 550;
0 Sat Aug 06 01:13:35 2011 +0600:
3 Wed Dec 14 04:01:33 2011 +0600: add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');
6 Sun Jun 24 15:20:24 2012 +0600: add_theme_support('custom-background');
```

With revision number (only) you can see file at the state of this revision: `hg cat -r N <filename>`

But if you want to see all history of changes of string in question (and you have *some current or historical* content, not only number), you can [use `hg grep`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13549925/960558)